# I need to render my webview after prop in my redux change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, webview

I need to render a webview with a js injected, but this js is dynamic and is set after a call to my API.

When I navigate to the screen where is the webview, the api request is still running and I don't have the js to inject.

What I need is to inform my component that it will render the webview when the prop "success" is true in my redux

I've tried this:

```
render() {
  return (
    <View>
     {!this.props.oauth.success 
      ? <Text style={styles.loading}> Loading...</Text>
      : this.renderWebView()}
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: This looks fine. Try posting more code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the webview, when inside a view, has to have width property in styles.

Thanks!